# How to remove elements from lists in dictionaries based on condition in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are lists of strings. Below is a sample from a much larger dictionary I am working with.A problem I'm running into is that the keys sometimes appear in the values (ie. key '25-3' contains '25-3' and I'd like to remove it.

```py
cat_map = {'11-1': ['41-4', '43-1', '11-2', '43-6'],
 '11-2': ['41-4', '43-1', '11-2', '43-6'],
 '11-3': [],
 '11-9': [],
 '13-1': [],
 '13-2': [],
 '15-1': [],
 '15-2': [],
 '17-1': [],
 '17-2': [],
 '17-3': [],
 '19-1': [],
 '19-2': [],
 '19-3': [],
 '19-4': [],
 '21-1': [],
 '21-2': ['43-2', '33-9', '39-6', '39-9', '25-3', '39-3', '39-7'],
 '23-1': [],
 '23-2': [],
 '25-1': [],
 '25-2': [],
 '25-3': ['43-2', '37-1', '39-6', '25-3', '39-3'],
```

I'm puzzled why the below didn't work

```py
for k,v in cat_map.items():
    for item in v:
        if k == item:
            del cat_map[cat_map[k].index(item)]
        else:
            continue
```

See the error (KeyError2)

```py
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-f4c2c0fde28b> in <module>
      2     for item in v:
      3         if k== item:
----> 4             del cat_map[cat_map[k].index(item)]
      5         else:
      6             continue

KeyError: 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not accessing the lists correctly. You would want to do:

```py
del cat_map[k][cat_map[k].index(item)]
```

but you could simplify this check by:

```py
for k,v in cat_map.items():
    if k in v:
        v.remove(k)
```

Comment: Thanks! I way overthought it.

Comment: It's ok @mjake, this multi-level accessing can get quite confusing. Try to break it down square-bracket by square-bracket to understand it better. But of course is better to use simplified expressions where possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary comprehension to build up the dictionary that you want to keep:

```
cat_map = {k:v for k,v in cat_map.items() if not k in v}
```

If you want to keep the entry but just change the values, you could use (as Tomerikoo observes in the comments):

```
cat_map = {k:[x for x in v if x != k] for k,v in cat_map.items()}
```

Comment: I tried this and it mostly worked but items where the key was duplicated in the values were deleted, as in the keys were removed as well.

Comment: @mjake I don't understand -- isn't this what you want to do?

Comment: You need `cat_map = {k:[x for x in v if x != k] for k,v in cat_map.items()}`

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You say "I'd like to remove it. " without ever saying what "it" refers to. I read it as wanting to remove the dictionary entry, but you seem to only want to remove the key from the *value*. @Tomerikoo has the right idea about doing the latter (thanks!). I will edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:

- Using `del cat_map[cat_map[k].index(item)]`, `cat_map[k].index(item)` will return index of item which is an integer not available in `cat_map` dictionary. Hence, the **`KeyError`**.

Use list **`remove`**, but only with a membership check prior to that.

Here's the code:

```
for k, v in cat_map.items():
    if k in v:
        v.remove(k)
```

Comment: Appreciate it, you and @Tomerikoo were right on the money

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = list(cat_map.keys())

for key, value in cat_map.items():
    for index, element in enumerate(value):
        if element in key:
            del cat_map[key][index]
```

Comment: This checks if a value contains **any** key. The question asks for just values containing their own key. You could just delete the `keys` list and simply check `if element == key`

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code answered the question.

Comment: well @pppery it doesn't quite answer the question as I explained in the previous comment

Comment: @Tomerikoo I guess I fixed it. It should be `if element in key` right ?